# Recommended tools for UI-testing a jQuery-intensive website

Tags: jquery, testing

I have a jQuery-intensive website and I am looking for a tool to automate testing on major browsers.

Please note that I am already implementing unit testing with QUnit -what I want to test now is clicking on the links and other interactions with the UI elements.

What tools could I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't yet, try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: You can use Sizzle based CSS selectors to locate the elements using Selenium. Try it.